# Android app running but not installed

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android app development, till last day it was going smooth, but today when I run my app from **Android Studio**, it's running in both emulator and in my Sony mobile. But I couldn't able to find it once I close the app, **i.e** the app is not installed, but running fine.

Comment: Please post your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

There must be a entry point of the application. This is usually denoted by the intent-filter as shown here:

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Inside the activity tag in the AndroidManifest.xml